# Daily Script Error Reports - ReferenceError: "errorHandling_" is not defined. (line X, file "Code")

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I use this basic import range scipt but receive multiple daily script error reports. The Script seems to do what I need it today so I do not understand what the error is referencing or means. Can someone help and explain?

(1.) ReferenceError: "errorHandling_" is not defined. (line 10, file "Code")

(2.) ReferenceError: "errorHandling_" is not defined. (line 8, file "Absence")

1. var values = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1MJ7D7vOWWPgJBO5MZtZHyPw6Iw0kNlZ8Y5OIwSdzBUg').
   getSheetByName('Form responses 1').getRange('a:F').getValues();
   SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Overtime Activities (Do not edit)').
   getRange(3,1,values.length,values[0].length).setValues(values);

   function timeDriven(e) {

   if( e !== undefined )
   errorHandling_(monitor_,true);
   }
2. var values = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1fdOI61__16jFCEDJCvWHtVMu6BhkxS88x5408-JB8oA').
   getSheetByName('main').getRange('a:g').getValues();
   SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Absence & Lateness (Do not edit)').
   getRange(3,1,values.length,values[0].length).setValues(values);

   function timeDriven(e) {

   if( e !== undefined )
   errorHandling_(monitor_,true);
   }

Answer (score 0):

You probably mistyped the name of this function : `errorHandling_(parameters)` or you forgot to include it in your project.

Your scrip might work partially before it tries to execute the error handling or if no error occurred.

Comment: I see, so do I need it, can i delete without compromising the script. Sorry for my ignorance with this...

Comment: I could answer if I knew the whole content of your script... but with only the part you show I can't. Either share a copy of your doc or edit your answer with full code.